# `SDK` packages in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

What are *SDK* packages in eclipse? When I try to install a new software / plugin, I see things like -

- C/C++ Development Tools
- C/C++ Development Tools SDK

- Mobile Tools for Java
- Mobile Tools for Java SDK

etc. Not all packages have a second with an *SDK*, but some do. What are the differences between the two? What does CDT provide me and what does CDT SDK provide me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SDK features typically include source and developer documentation for building on the base project, so it would be the viewable sources for CDT and documentation on how to plug into it where possible.  If you're just using the tools to write your own programs, the SDK feature is typically not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In simple, C++ tool is compiler etc. tools. And C++ SDK is C++ provided libraries that might be used in your project.